# How do I link imported questions with Imported answers?

Tags: python, import

I am a student at high-school and we are left to create a maths question answer game. We are given Questions and Answers in Excel to import into the program and it asks a random questions (from the ones given) and you have to be told if you have got the question correct or not.

I am stuck at this point where the program asks the question but I am unsure how to get the answer to match with the question given.

here is my code to see what I have done, any information helps.

```
    csv_file = open("questions.csv", "r")    

    question_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter = ",")

    for row in question_reader:
        The_que = row[0]
        The_ans = row[1]

        self.questions.append(equation(The_que, The_ans)) 

    csv_file.close()

    for question in self.questions:
        question.display()

    from random import randint
    ran_num = randint(0,20)

    print(self.questions[ran_num].question)
    random_question = (self.questions[ran_num].question)

    self.label_1 = Label(parent, bg= "Black",
                                 fg = "Pink", 
                                 text = random_question,
                                 padx=30,
                                 pady=10,
                                 font =("times", "14", "bold " ))
    self.label_1.pack()
    self.button_1 = Button(parent,
                           text = "Lock in Answer",
                           command = self.Answer_entry)
    self.button_1.pack()

    self.entry_1 = Entry(parent)
    self.entry_1.pack()

def Answer_entry(self):
    the_text = self.entry_1.get()
    self.label_1.configure(text = the_text)
```

So There is more to the code that I haven't linked but I think this will good to show. Right now I have

```
      the_text
```

as a placeholder
.

**Reminder** I am a High school student who started programming 3-5 weeks ago so please try to explain this like it is to a 5 year old since I am not great at this.